executing dynamic sql in oracle
With DYN_DateCheck As
(Select 'Select ' || ''''|| TABLE_NAME ||'''' || ' As Tbl, ' || ''''|| COLUMN_NAME||'''' || ' As Fld, ' || 'Check_Date(' || COLUMN_NAME || ', :dateformat) As ValidDate ' || 
         'From '   || TABLE_NAME  || '_TST ' ||
         'Where '  || COLUMN_NAME || ' IS NOT NULL UNION'
  From  all_tab_columns 
  Where NOT OWNER  In ('SYS', 'XDB', 'GSMADMIN_INTERNAL' ) 
  And TABLE_NAME   In ('EGL_CLIENTDETAIL', 'STG_PLY', 'STG_PLR', 'STG_IAC', 'STG_PPD')
  And   DATA_TYPE   = 'DATE'
  UNION
  Select 'Select ' || '''XYZ''' || ' As Tbl, ' || '''XYZ''' || ' As Fld, NULL As ValidDate From Dual' From Dual
  Order By 1
)
Select * From (Select * From DYN_DateCheck)

You probably already know this final Select statement won't actually execute all of the Selects / Unions in DYN_DateCheck - it just provides the dynamic SQL. How can I execute the dynamic Select statements that are in DYN_DateCheck?
I've tried Execute Immediate - I don't really understand that but I don't how to continue using what is executed. I need to use the results from when this dynamic sql runs.

A closer look reveals the following:

we don't know what is function you use (check_date); it looks as if you're passing column name and :dateformat, but it smells wrong as date datatype values aren't stored in any human-readable format, so that might make sense if you wanted to check whether a string - that looks like a date - follows certain format.
For testing purposes, I just created a dummy function which doesn't do anything.

table you're trying to query has a _tbl suffix; I don't have it, so I removed the suffix as well

as of too many rows error you reported: it is due to misused union set operator; you should have unioned two select statements in dynamic part of that query (see code I'm going to post)


OK, here we go: function first:
SQL> create or replace function check_date (par_date in date)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return 1;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

A simple option is to copy result of that statement, paste it (at SQL*Plus prompt or into GUI tool you might be using) and then execute it.
SQL>  With DYN_DateCheck (col) As
  2      (Select 'Select ' || ''''|| TABLE_NAME ||'''' || ' As Tbl, ' || ''''|| COLUMN_NAME||'''' || ' As Fld, ' || 'Check_Date(' || COLUMN_NAME || ') As ValidDate ' ||
  3               ' From '   || TABLE_NAME  || -- '_TST ' ||
  4               ' Where '  || COLUMN_NAME || ' IS NOT NULL UNION ' ||
  5               ' Select ' || '''XYZ''' || ' As Tbl, ' || '''XYZ''' || ' As Fld, NULL As ValidDate From Dual'
  6        From  all_tab_columns
  7        Where owner = 'SCOTT'
  8        And TABLE_NAME   In ('EMP')
  9        And   DATA_TYPE   = 'DATE'
 10      )
 11      Select *
 12  from dyn_datecheck;

COL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Select 'EMP' As Tbl, 'HIREDATE' As Fld, Check_Date(HIREDATE) As ValidDate  From
EMP Where HIREDATE IS NOT NULL UNION  Select 'XYZ' As Tbl, 'XYZ' As Fld, NULL As
 ValidDate From Dual

Above statement is copy/pasted at the prompt and - here's the result:
SQL> Select 'EMP' As Tbl, 'HIREDATE' As Fld, Check_Date(HIREDATE) As ValidDate  From
  2  EMP Where HIREDATE IS NOT NULL UNION  Select 'XYZ' As Tbl, 'XYZ' As Fld, NULL As
  3   ValidDate From Dual;

TBL FLD       VALIDDATE
--- -------- ----------
EMP HIREDATE          1
XYZ XYZ

SQL>


If you want to automate it, convert that code into a function that returns refcursor and then call the function.
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_query varchar2(4000);
  5    rc sys_Refcursor;
  6  begin
  7      With DYN_DateCheck (col) As
  8      (Select 'Select ' || ''''|| TABLE_NAME ||'''' || ' As Tbl, ' || ''''|| COLUMN_NAME||'''' || ' As Fld, ' || 'Check_Date(' || COLUMN_NAME || ') As ValidDate ' ||
  9               ' From '   || TABLE_NAME  || -- '_TST ' ||
 10               ' Where '  || COLUMN_NAME || ' IS NOT NULL UNION ' ||
 11               ' Select ' || '''XYZ''' || ' As Tbl, ' || '''XYZ''' || ' As Fld, NULL As ValidDate From Dual'
 12        From  all_tab_columns
 13        Where owner = 'SCOTT'
 14        And TABLE_NAME   In ('EMP')
 15        And   DATA_TYPE   = 'DATE'
 16      )
 17      Select *
 18      into l_query
 19      From DYN_DateCheck;
 20
 21    open rc for l_query;
 22    return rc;
 23  end;
 24  /

Function created.

Testing:
SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

TBL FLD       VALIDDATE
--- -------- ----------
EMP HIREDATE          1
XYZ XYZ


SQL>


Thank you. I created that function as you did that has my exact code - thanks again for doing that. When I select f_test from dual I get this error. ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "OWNER_DATALOAD_UAT.F_TEST", line 7
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

What you selected when you tested it was only that final hardcoded row which is there only to ensure the final row doesn't have a union. The main part of that will retrieve multiple records.

Right; I checked what's going on here and modified the answer. Have a look, please.

Thanks for your help with this - I'm still getting the same error. I've noticed your query returns only 1 select record from the main part of the select, and then has that additional one unioned on the end of it - so still just one record is returned. My query returns around 24 records, which I'm thinking it's why I keep getting that error. These first records I've displayed here are what is selected when I put that additional union within the dynamic part of the query. You can see it shows up for every one of the select records the main part retrieves. The way I did that previous doesn't.

Select 'STG_PLY' As Tbl, 'PLY_CREATEDONDATE' As Fld, Check_Date(PLY_CREATEDONDATE, :dateformat) As ValidDate  From STG_PLY Where PLY_CREATEDONDATE IS NOT NULL UNION  Select 'XYZ' As Tbl, 'XYZ' As Fld, NULL As ValidDate From Dual
Select 'STG_PLY' As Tbl, 'PLY_EFFDATE' As Fld, Check_Date(PLY_EFFDATE, :dateformat) As ValidDate  From STG_PLY Where PLY_EFFDATE IS NOT NULL UNION  Select 'XYZ' As Tbl, 'XYZ' As Fld, NULL As ValidDate From Dual

Select 'STG_PPD' As Tbl, 'PPD_PRINTDATE' As Fld, Check_Date(PPD_PRINTDATE, :dateformat) As ValidDate  From STG_PPD_TST  Where PPD_PRINTDATE IS NOT NULL UNION
Select 'STG_PPD' As Tbl, 'PPD_RUNDATE' As Fld, Check_Date(PPD_RUNDATE, :dateformat) As ValidDate  From STG_PPD_TST  Where PPD_RUNDATE IS NOT NULL UNION
Select 'STG_PPD' As Tbl, 'PPD_TERMSOFTRADEDATE' As Fld, Check_Date(PPD_TERMSOFTRADEDATE, :dateformat) As ValidDate  From STG_PPD_TST  Where PPD_TERMSOFTRADEDATE IS NOT NULL UNION
Select 'XYZ' As Tbl, 'XYZ' As Fld, NULL As ValidDate From Dual

so the question now is how to retrieve all of those select statement rows that end with a union (except for that additional hard-coded final one) and return them into one row.

or maybe change the where clause on the function you created to ensure there is more than one table and column retrieved that has a date datatype. I think you'll get the same results I'm getting - that error that more than one record is retrieved.

I've got some output making some changes to try to surpress the query to be one row - but I don't get the same results as you - I don't understand that CURSOR STATEMENT : 1 that appears for you and then the results display - mine just shows as one long record, kind of like json or xml with everything in brackets {<TBL=STG_PLY,FLD=PLY_LASTRENDATE,VALIDDATE=01/APR/17>,}

Thanks again for the time you've spent and advice / code you've provided for me for this. Around the same time I asked this question on stackoverflow (the first one I've personally asked here - usually I just go looking for answers from previous posts) I also asked one of our DBAs - I really didn't think he'd have the time. Well, he did, or at least someone on his team did, and he provided me this. When I execute this sp, I can then select details or counts for anything in that table which will contain details for invalid dates.

create or replace PROCEDURE dynamic_query(p_date_format in varchar2) IS
query_str   VARCHAR2(1000);
date_format VARCHAR2(100);
type data_table_type IS TABLE OF TEST_DYNAMIC%ROWTYPE;
temp_data_table data_table_type;
BEGIN
execute immediate 'truncate table TEST_DYNAMIC';
date_format:=p_date_format;
for rec1 in (my dynamic sql)
LOOP
query_str := rec1.QUERY;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str BULK COLLECT INTO temp_data_table;
dbms_output.put_line (temp_data_table.count);

FOR i IN 1..temp_data_table.count
LOOP
If temp_data_table(i).VALIDDATE IS NULL and NOT temp_data_table(i).TBL = 'XYZ'
Then insert into TEST_DYNAMIC(TBL,FLD,VALIDDATE) values(temp_data_table(i).TBL,temp_data_table(i).FLD,temp_data_table(i).VALIDDATE);
End If;
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
commit;
END;
